How to add the font-family , font-color, and other components in the FloatingToolbarPlugin?
enter image description here
in this Image floating toolbar I need to add more components...
I expect to add the font Family, font color and background color in the floating toolbar?
the selection.hasFormat("") method support only some basic components..
